# Validando nulos con linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tengo la siguiente query en linq

```
using (var context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            var result = (from m in context.MovimientoCajas
                where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.Fecha) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fecha)
                      && m.PuntoEmisionId == puntoEmision && m.TipoMovimiento == MovimientoCajaType.Ingreso
                select m.Ingreso).Sum();
            return result;
        }
```

La query funciona bien pero cuando no hay datos en esa fecha porque no se ha ingresado nada aún me da el siguiente error.

> La conversión a valor de tipo 'System.Decimal' falló porque el valor
>   materializado es nulo. El parámetro genérico del tipo de resultado o
>   la consulta deben usar un tipo que pueda contener nulos.

Entiendo el problema, mi pregunta es si pudo validar en la misma linea del select `select m.Ingreso).Sum();` o necesariamente tengo que hacer un `select new`y castiarlo en una clase y mapearlo a una propiedad de tipo decimal. ¿Que es lo mas recomendable?

Comment: de casualidad la propiedad Ingreso permite null ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini A la propiedad de la clase no le he puesto aún

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si detectas que el problema es por la inexistencia de registros siempre puedes validarlo

```
var query = from m in context.MovimientoCajas
                where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.Fecha) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fecha)
                      && m.PuntoEmisionId == puntoEmision && m.TipoMovimiento == MovimientoCajaType.Ingreso
                select m.Ingreso;

if(query.Count > 0){
    return query.Sum();
}

return 0;
```

o tambien usar una linea

```
return query.Count == 0 ? 0 : query.Sum();
```

igualmente deberias validar que la propiedad `Ingreso` no permita null, ya que no tener un dato causaria problemas

Comment: Muchas gracias @Leandro

Answer (score 0):

Puedes castear a Nullable la propiedad **m.Ingreso** y luego con el operador **??** le digo que si es null, retorne 0.

```
var result = (from m in context.MovimientoCajas
                      where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.Fecha) ==DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fecha)
                            && m.PuntoEmisionId == puntoEmision && m.TipoMovimiento == MovimientoCajaType.Ingreso
                      select m.Ingreso as decimal? ?? 0).Sum();
```